# Calling Method in onCreateView()

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext

Hi I am new to fragments and I am working with this activity.I populated an edit text but I want to highlight the borders when the user focus on one of the edit text.I created the method focus and I am calling it,but it is not working.

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public class Fragment_Info extends Fragment {

EditText CompanyName;
EditText CompanyOwner;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment__info, container, false);

    CompanyName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.CompName);
    CompanyOwner = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.CompOwner);
    focus(CompanyName);
    focus(CompanyOwner);

    //Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment__info, container, false);
}

public void focus(View view){
    view.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus)
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.focus_border_style);
            else
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimary);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are applying focus on a view and returning a different view from the method.

Change

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment__info, container, false);
```

to

```
return view;
```

Comment: u beat me in answering fast

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
   return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment__info, container, false);
```

to

```
return view;
```